# Hybrid SharePoint 2010 On-Premise with AWS EC2 (manage DB SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sql-server-2012, amazon-ec2

We have requirement one of client to maintain that SharePoint 2010 Server on our local Server instead of AWS EC2 and SharePoint Databases (Like SP_Config,WSS_Content, Service application databases)  should be maintain in AWS EC2 (SQL Server 2012 R2).

First, I would like to know is it possible to hybrid solution [on-premise server with AWS EC2 (only for Database)]?

If yes, can you please guide us what's are steps needs to be taken care while migrating SQL Server content, config and service application database on AWS EC2?

Highly appreciate your quick response !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but it is not supported( if not meet the requirement). Your 
topology falls under the stretched farm which has very high requirement.

- There is a highly consistent intra-farm latency of <1ms (one way),
  99.9% of the time over a period of ten minutes. (Intra-farm latency is commonly defined as the latency between the front-end web servers
  and the database servers.)
- The bandwidth speed must be at least 1 gigabit per second.

[Read more here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748824.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#CfgStretchedFarm)

[Also check this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/berryst/2011/04/05/setting-up-sharepoint-2010-stretched-farm/)